# OT.Publisher.onStreamAvailableError NotAllowedError: Unknown Error while getting user media

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, opentok

As the session is connected, without showing the permission dialog, the browser directly throws an access denied message (cannot access microphone or camera) with this error in the console

`"OT.Publisher.onStreamAvailableError Permission Denied".`

This error comes only when i m hosting my site through local IIS server not for localhost.

This error come in only Updated browser of Firefox 68+ and Chrome 73+ not in older versions of browser like 57.

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly give microphone and camera permission from your browser and then see what happens?